# $all not working in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two document in my collections

```
{ participants: [ '5ab8fcf6d8bfca2cc0aebb37', '5ab8fd15d8bfca2cc0aebb38' ],
    _id: 5ab9a5a0cb274a2064b65d1b,
    __v: 0 
},
{ participants: [ '5ab8fcf6d8bfca2cc0aebb37', '5ab8fcf6d8bfca2cc0aebb37' ],
    _id: 5ab9a5a7cb274a2064b65d1c,
    __v: 0
}
```

and i have an array of persons like

```
persons = [ 5ab8fcf6d8bfca2cc0aebb37, '5ab8fcf6d8bfca2cc0aebb37' ]
```

Now I am trying to find a document which contains which contain `participants` fields similar to array `persons` using this query.

```
Participant.find({participants: {$all: persons}}).exec()
        .then(connected => {
            console.log(connected);
            // perform some stuff
});
```

it throws me both document as an output.
I  don't know what is the problem.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is the [`$setEquals`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/) operator.

```
db.collection.find({ $expr: { $setEquals: [ persons, "$participants" ] } } )
```

You can use the `$setEquals` operator with the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/redact) operator if the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator is not available in the `mongod` version you're running.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `$eq` operator as well

```
    Participant.find( { participants: { $eq: persons } })
      .then(connected => {
                console.log(connected);
                // perform some stuff
    });
```

for more https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/

Comment: `$in` will also gives all the entries having one of the specified ids. He wants only entries that matches exactly the ids list.

Comment: Ok for the $eq answer :) You should remove the `$in` soluce which doesn't work

Comment: [`$eq` will fail if the order of the elements in both array is not the same](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#match-an-array-value).

Comment: @styvane Question says "similar to array"... so by that statment it is correct